# Cookie encryption and decryption using Servlet filters

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, encryption

Is any function or api available to intercept addCookie() so that the cookies set by the servlet will be encrypted using servlet filters. And when the getCookies() is invoked the filter would decrypt it and give the response back to web server.

Actually all this is done to prevent XSS attack. I am not able to find any documentation or info. regarding encryption and decryption of cookies using servlet Filters.. Any help would be gratefull.